# Wrong Week Numbers Displayed In Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

The data in a pivot table is displaying wrong week numbers for given dates, essentially the weeknum is ahead by 1 week,

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: @HafizSb No. `11-Oct-21` is week 41.

Comment: https://imgur.com/SaMf9qL `Excel 2016` is showing `42`  @Gravitate

Comment: @HafizSb It shows as week 41 on mine. Could this depend on the date/time settings on the local machine? I thought ISOWEEKNUM was the same everywhere?

Comment: @HafizSb Ah... you are using `WEEKNUM` and I am using `ISOWEEKNUM`. Not entirely sure of the difference, except `WEEKNUM` defaults to Sunday being the first day of the week, where as `ISOWEEKNUM` is a Monday. I am not sure what the OP is using but I suggest they try the opposite of what they currently are.

Comment: Function `ISOWeeknum` is used to return the week number (for a specified date) in the year. It follows the `ISO (International organization for Standardization)` week number.
`=ISOWEEKNUM("1/6/2019")` and Function `Weeknum` is used to return the week number (for a specified date) in the year. It has 2 parameters and the 2nd parameter is used to define the weeks beginning on specific day.
 `=WEEKNUM("01/6/2019",1)` - Here 1 is used for Sunday as 1st day of week. You are right @Gravitate

Comment: Thanks, I used `WEEKNUM` function, i have now switched to the `ISOWEEKNUM`. somehow thought this might be a pivot table related issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared your raw data but I assume you have used the `WEEKNUM` function.

I think the problem you are having is due to using `WEEKNUM` instead of `ISOWEEKNUM`.

`WEEKNUM` starts counting weeks from the very first day of the year, which results in not every week having 7 days.

`ISOWEEEKNUM` ensures every week has 7 days but does mean that one week can run over 2 years (which can cause it's own issues).

Please see the table below showing how the results of the two functions vary:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pivot tabel is displaying the wrong weeknumber, even though I’m using ISOWEEKNUM in my data:
Jan 1st, 2023 was a Sunday, and since ISOWEEKNUM uses the first week of the year that contains a Thursday week number 1 starts on Jan 2 (Monday). Yet when I create a pivot it starts with week 2. Or, rather, displays week 2. It’s a bug in the pivot table, still here in the latest version of Excel (also for the Mac btw)

Comment: Could be a comment, not an answer. Not so clear, also the formatting is not helping.